# Unimodular matrix to increase the minimum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

Given a positive definite matrix $P$, I would like to find a unimodular matrix $U$ so that $U P U^T$ raises the minimum eigenvalue as much as possible.

How can one find such a matrix $U$?

Comment: Have you tried diagonalizing $P$?

Comment: I didn't realize it had to be an integer matrix, my mistake.